# Unable to mint an NFT with new contract,. Error: 'Returned error: execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner'

Tags: solidity, nft, mint, alchemy

I've returned on a project I worked before the merge of ETH Blockchain and the project was just a demo so I never tried it successfully.

I've updated my contract and when I peform the

```
  var gasEstimate = await nftContract.methods.mintNFT(publicKey,metadataUri).estimateGas();
```

I got this error:

'Returned error: execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner'

I'm on goerli network and the contract has the following address

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xc2eedaf40abea9aa529c7b2f230173caf54b01a0

Why it tell's it's not the owner... I use the public/private key of my ETH test account

I've seen [this post][1] but I don't know how to verify the contract's owner.

Here's my contract btw

```
// SPDX-License-Idenier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract EttNFT is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("myNft", "mynft") {}

    function mintNft(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
}
```

Thanks
[1]: [Fail with error 'Ownable: caller is not the owner'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93589/fail-with-error-ownable-caller-is-not-the-owner)

Comment: I just updated the answer to include a Python script to call the owner function of the contract that you put in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here!

The `mintNft`function has the `onlyOwner` modifier declared in it. This means that that function can only be called by the owner of the smart contract, which is the address that deployed the contract.

```
    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }
```

The `onlyOwner` modifier calls the `checkOwner` function, which gives an error if the caller of the function `msg.sender` is not the owner.

```
    /**
     * @dev Throws if the sender is not the owner.
     */
    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }
```

The `owner` function lets you see which address is the owner. You can try to call it to see which of your address is the owner!

```
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }
```

If you lost access to the address owning the contract, you would need to re-deploy it from another one :)

### Call owner function with Python

I used this python script to call the owner function on that contract address you attached to your question.

```py
from web3 import Web3

node_url = "YOUR_NODE_ENDPOINT"

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_url))

abi = '[{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"uri","type":"string"}],"name":"safeMint","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'

contract_address = "0xC2eedAF40ABEA9Aa529c7b2f230173cAf54b01A0"

contract = web3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=abi)

# verify the connection is successful (will return true)
if web3.isConnected():
    print("Connection Successful")
else:
    print("Connection Failed")

print(web3.eth.block_number)

owner = contract.functions.owner().call()

print(owner)
```

I just took the ABI from an ownable ERC721 contract built from the [OpenZeppelin wizard](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#erc721).

This is the address that owns that contract!

0x294262758f44Df35e856AEb7a2dA9b3830232A12

You can also check on Etherscan the contract that created the contract!

[contract creation](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x926cad9ea5f0f8a0e62cadc1bae3cd4d9a35cc23df60d048d3eb9bbb3e9c74c7)

If you need a Goerli endpoint, you can use [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com)!

Comment: Hello @Soos3D, thanks for your reply... but I don't understand a thing, being the signer of the contract, why it says that I'm not allowed to mint an NFT that again I sign with my public/private key it give me that error? Another question... currently I'm using alchemy but when I ask what NFT I own I get 0...what I fear is that I'm not considered the owner, that's why I used a contract with the Ownder interface...